# Burninate the [invisible] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I was just reading this question: [Line with StrokeThickness = 1 disappears when coordinates are outside its parent grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950562/line-with-strokethickness-1-disappears-when-coordinates-are-outside-its-parent), and I noticed it was tagged with [invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invisible).  This tag does not have a wiki summary, nor does it add any value to this question.  What, if any, value does this tag provide?  Should this tag be removed?

**Edit:**

In response to the posted answer, I still feel that [invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invisible) provides no value to the site.  I cannot judge whether [visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visible) provides value, as I do not know these languages.

Comment: Could be great tag on magic.se

Comment: Maybe. It doesn't seem to be especially relevant here, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I was really hoping to learn about a secret tag that cannot be seen by users. I'm deeply disappointed :(

Comment: It might be a tag that came about by people typing complete sentences into the tag field.

Comment: @TimSeguine I don't think people with such privilege would make this mistake.

Comment: opposite end of the spectrum there is a `visible` tag.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visible

Comment: @vitor yeah,  probably.  Just saying whatever it's original purpose,  it is the type of tag that would get used this way.

Comment: @Sam We should create `yes` and `no` tags just in case we aren't talking about visibility.

Comment: "This tag does not have a wiki summary" - it does. You just can't see it.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Sorry I don't understand. Do you mean that I shouldn't have bought it up? It does specifically mention the Invisible tag in it's description. "Opposite of [tag::hidden] or [tag::invisible] depending upon context."

Comment: @Sam I told a joke actually. It's just more useless than `invisible`; they could just use `visibility`.

Comment: Clearly [tag:invisible] should have a blank tag wiki description.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this tag doesn't have a very specific meaning, but people are using it sometimes if the question is related to something that is not visible/hidden/not rendered or something disappeared.

Here are some examples (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invisible for more):

- [Protractor : wait for element to become invisible/hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411574/protractor-wait-for-element-to-become-invisible-hidden)
- [Start php.exe invisible with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686828/start-php-exe-invisible-with-c)
- [Android - fixed size cells for tableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639758/android-fixed-size-cells-for-tablelayout)
- [OpenUI5 controls not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732823/openui5-controls-not-visible)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991931/word-colored-hyperlinks-inside-a-file-but-not-in-printed
- [jsPlumb Endpoint visible: false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807883/jsplumb-endpoint-visible-false)

Some different examples, where a programming language really contains a function or an attribute named **visible**:

- [R returns undesired output to screen or drops some return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688497/r-returns-undesired-output-to-screen-or-drops-some-return-values).
- [jsPlumb Endpoint visible: false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807883/jsplumb-endpoint-visible-false)

As you may know, tags can be created by users with at least 1500 reputation.

Comment: OK, I see.  I was looking at questions with the first use, and I while the question was related to something being invisible, I didn't think it was that important of a distinguishing feature.

Answer (score 3):

Should be removed. The question should be tagged with the language or technology used and not with `invisible`... There isn't anyone who knows in every single language or tech why something would be invisible.