# All [ratio]s are now empty

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Several weeks ago I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26624378/4186297) question. It was about calculating ratio of sides of rectangle in Scala. I received 5 upvotes and on my tag list I had [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) tag with score 5. I Quickly realized that I can easily gain 5 points in different tags. All I had to do was to edit question and add more tags to it. So I added [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) and [rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) tags. And several hours later I had those two tags on my list with score 5. I was so happy. I thought that maybe it is first little step to becoming expert in [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio). I could even become the best [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) expert in my city.

My excitation evaporated when I looked in the list of [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tagged questions. There were so many various topics. There were questions about HTML, CSS, images, math. In every question there was some kind of ratio (some proportion) but in most questions it was unimportant. Then I realized that [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tag has no sense because:

1. You cannot be expert in [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio). There is not much knowledge connected with this tag. You can be an expert in (for example) 'prime numbers' but not in [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio)
2. This tag doesn't have followers. I cannot imagine a reason to follow this tag.
3. I don't see a reason to search questions using this tag.
4. If there is a question tagged only [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) then I really don't know what it question is about.
5. There is [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize), which is more specific and can embrace many [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) questions.
6. Occurrence of 'ratio' word in question is not enough reason to tag question with [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio). such as occurrence of 'bicycle' word is not enough to tag with [bicycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bicycle)

So I vote for 'burninate'.

Comment: For some reason I'm now sorely tempted to try my hand at becoming the greatest ratio expert in the world, complete with Golden Ratio badge.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There's still a [ratio tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratio) over at Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @tepples: well, that kills the temptation. I'm pretty sure I can't compete there.

Comment: Aside: What's up with [rect] and [rectangles]?

Comment: @JeroenMostert now I want to hone my skills at math to get a *golden* golden ration badge.

Comment: This is similar to my question about [tag:invisible].  In the end, my question just died.

Comment: @hosch250 maybe your question did not have enough visibility here on Meta.

Comment: @Renan Maybe.  I'll edit it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276914/2509848

Comment: But if you burninate the `ratio` tag, won't all those questions become irrational?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +64/-4. Answer (Saying neither) : +5/0

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not start removing the tag from questions until the community has decided whether to move forward with the burnination or not.

Comment: @DamianYerrick That ratio tag over at Maths Stack Exchange might not be 1:1 with the SO one

Comment: It's too late for a punny title now, but I'm surprised no-one came up with "This tag should be [ratio]d out of existence".

Comment: There has been 6 additional downvotes since it was featured, which is quite significant. I'll be leaving this for another day, to see if there is any answer asking to not burn the tag.

Comment: what do you mean `burninate`? thats not even a word

Comment: There is a `<ratio>` header in C++ for compile-time rational arithmetic for which a tag may be appropriate.

Comment: There's wind of a new HTML `ratio` input coming to browsers near you. I vote no!

Comment: Burninate is totally a word... it's a strong bad word

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +130/-11. Answer (Saying neither): +17/0. Given the large number of upvotes on the post and no opposing answers, the community has voted to burninate the tag.

Comment: This is pointless busywork.

Answer (score 19):

I thought we got rid of rectangle, already: [Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/remove-triangle).

Anyhow, I'll say the same thing about [rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) that I said there. It should be replaced with [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) (when it's actually geometry relate, of course).

Additionally, there might also be cases where retagging [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) to something like [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) is appropriate.

Comment: The math tag is worthless too. Programming itself is applied mathematics. If everything is math, then mentioning it doesn't help.

Comment: @dfeuer "Programming itself is applied mathematics." I *strongly* disagree. So much of what we do has nothing to do with math. We spend a lot of time focusing on good style, performance, choosing good existing tools and techniques, and a host of other topics that have nothing to do with math.

Comment: @jpmc26: Mathematicians also spend time on properly formatting their papers, proper latex formatting, making clear proofs that are easily readable, etc.

Comment: @Claudiu They do, so I should rephrase that. Often times, our applications are decidedly non-mathematical. (Is implementing and extending a CMS "math"? How about UX?) I won't deny that there are important aspects of math involved in our profession or that they may even be getting more important (functional programming, for instance), but to say "programming is applied math" is an *enormous* overstatement of how much most developers deal with math on a daily basis. If I had to pick one phrase to describe what we do, I would pick "automate processes" over "math" any day.

Comment: [tag:rectangle] is gone but [tag:rectangles] and [tag:rect] are still going strong

Comment: As a mathematics major @jpmc26 I'd disagree. I think the statement "Programming itself is applied mathematics" is false, and you're correct on that point, but I think programming could be defined as the application of a logistical mathematical mindset for logical solution sets.

Comment: @RileyCarney Given the lack of rigor I see in most developers' approaches, I'd have to strongly disagree with that as well.

Comment: @jpmc26 you could have a lack of rigor in mathematics as well and it's a disaster. From my experience I believe Mathematics is programming. There are so many common ideas between both fields and every piece of code you write and decision you make can be written with a mathematical proof. Mathematics by itself is a form of abstraction, so you can make every idea and concept as general as you'd like, and translate any code you write to the same idea. From a Turing Machine model, you can replicate any computer's code logic, and writing a language in the present day-and-age is like using thousands

Comment: of proofs (aka libraries) which you utilize in order to create larger logistical sets in order to create a solution from data which is provided.
Edit: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics

Comment: @RileyCarney Right, and it's not enough of a disaster in programming to drive the entire industry toward hard proofs. So clearly something is different.

Comment: @jpmc26 Proofs are common in algorithm design and analysis, though. There's a reason that Computer Science actually started out as a concentration of a Mathematics degree at many universities. The actual programming itself and algorithm design is indeed almost entirely math. That said, being a software developer involves a lot more than just programming and algorithm design. Most of the other tasks (requirements gathering, system design, UX, testing, documentation, cost/benefit analysis, etc.) are more engineering than math (hence the term "software engineering.")

Answer (score 6):

[ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) for programming questions related to mathematics.
- Use [fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fractions) for fractional numbers.
- Use [aspect-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aspect-ratio) for questions related to the ratio between width and height.

## Progress:

The [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=ratio),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bratio%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bratio%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bratio%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bratio%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186675)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.